# LoDash: How to remove null values and index of null values from two arrays with _.flow?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

### Problem

I have an array of arrays:

```
const multiple = [[1, 2, null, 7], [6, 8, 9, 1]]
```

Now I'd like to remove all null values and the corresponding element from the other array which results in:

```
[[1, 2, 7], [6, 8, 1]]
```

I'm able to do that but I'm looking for a solution with `_.flow`.

### Approach

This is my approach that doesn't return an array of arrays and also doesn't remove the element from the other array.

```
_.flow([
      xorWith(_.isNull)
])([1, 2, null, 7], [6, 8, 9, 1])
```

---

### 1. Update

My input will always be `[[ // Elements], [ // Elements]]`. It wasn't clear at my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const multiple = [[1, 2, null, 7], [6, 8, 9, 1]];
const withoutNulls = (arr) => _.every(arr, _.negate(_.isNull));

const result = _.flow(
  _.zip,
  (tuples) => _.filter(tuples, withoutNulls),
  _.unzip 
)(...multiple)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Genius! I had to add this to `_.zip`: `values => zip.apply(this, values)`

Answer (score 0):

Does that suit your needs, or you want it exactly with your functions set?
I can't get the basic idea of yours, because the flow function accepts functions and call them in chain, but it is not as in your case.

```js
_.flow((...args) => _.map(args, arr => _.filter(arr, v => !_.isNull(v))), console.log)([1, 2, null, 7], [6, 8, 9, 1])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach. You are right, I wasn't clear at my approach. My input will always be `[[ // Elements], [ // Elements]]`.